# Unable to connect to Elasticsearch with PHP inside Docker

Tags: php, elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes_from:
        - app
    links:
        - elastic

app:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:2.3
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    expose:
      - "9200"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
```

When I try to access Elasticsearch by going to `localhost:9200` it works.

But when I try to create an index using PHP I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException: No alive
>   nodes found in your cluster in

Here is the client code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Elasticsearch;

use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

    class Client 
    {
        public static function getClient()
        {
            return ClientBuilder::create()
                ->build();
        }
    }
```

Code to instantiate an Elasticsearch object:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Elasticsearch\Client;
use App\Elasticsearch\Indices\UserIndex;

$es = Client::getClient();
```

If I `var_dump($es)`, it dumps the Elasticsearch client object.

But when I attempt to create an index it throws an error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Elasticsearch\Indices;

use App\Elasticsearch\Indices\AbstractIndex;
use Elasticsearch\Client; 

    class UserIndex extends AbstractIndex
    {
        public function __construct(Client $client)
        {
            $this->client = $client;
        }
    }

    // Create User Index
    $userIndex = new UserIndex($es);
    var_dump($userIndex->createIndex('users'));
```

**Update**

From [enter link description here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/300)

this page. I tried to

```
$es = Client::getClient();

try {
    // Create User Index
    $userIndex = new UserIndex($es);
    var_dump($userIndex->createIndex('users'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($es->transport->getLastConnection()->getLastRequestInfo());
}
```

and now it shows me Curl error i.e

> ["curl"] array(2) { ["error"] "Failed to connect to localhost port
>   9200: Connection refused" ["errno"] 7

Comment: Looks like a port issue indeed (a bit as in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/408#issuecomment-207045443)

Comment: Also a bit like https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/425#issuecomment-231548912

Comment: how do you access the elastic from php?

Comment: @opHASnoNAME I updated that part in question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tried to connect to localhost, but you need to connect to "elastic" host.
try to connect to elasticsearch from php like this:

```
$hosts = [
    'elastic', // elastic host was added to you hosts file automatically
];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
   ->setHosts($hosts)
   ->build();
```

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

Comment: That didn't help. Actually app: is my data only container (not sure if i am using right term, just started learning docker). If you see php: i already have link to elastic.

Comment: yes, my mistake, a thought app container is executable, but it is only container for php files.

Comment: May be issue is ommision setting elastic host in factory Client::getClient();
try add setHost() calling.
return ClientBuilder::create()->setHost(['elastic']])->build();

if it does't work show /etc/hosts of php container, please!

Comment: That works man ! can you explain what you have just suggested.

Comment: Docker creates a virtual network between containers. You defined in your docker-compose.yml file 4 services (containers) with names nginx, php, app, elastic. When 2 services is linked docker compose adds route information about other service into /etc/hosts file. hostname of service is name of service into docker-compose file. (there is a "elastic")